# use python's sklearn module with custom dataset

Tags: python, node.js, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I've never used python before and I find myself in the dire need of using sklearn module in my node.js project for machine learning purposes.

I have been all day trying to understand the code examples in said module and now that I kind of understand how they work, I don't know how to use my own data set.

Each of the built in data sets has its own function (`load_iris`, `load_wine`, `load_breast_cancer`, etc) and they all load data from a .csv and an .rst file. I can't find a function that will allow me to load my own data set. (there's a `load_data` function but it seems to be for internal use of the previous three I mentioned, cause I can't `import` it)

How could I do that? What's the proper way to use sklearn with any other data set? Does it always have to be a .csv file? Could it be programmatically provided data (array, object, etc)?

In case it's important: all those built-in data sets have numeric features, my data set has both numeric and string features to be used in the decision tree.

Thanks

Comment: `load_XXX` are scikit-learn functions to load sprcific datasets. If you have your own dataset you just load it using numpy/pandas/whatever. I do not see the point of the question. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load whatever you want and then use `sklearn` models.

If you have a `.csv` file, `pandas` would be the best option.

```
import pandas as pd

mydataset = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")

X = mydataset.values[:,0:10] # let's assume that the first 10 columns are the features/variables
y = mydataset.values[:,11] # let's assume that the 11th column has the target values/classes
...
sklearn_model.fit(X,y)
```

Similarily, you can load `.txt` or `.xls` files.

The important thing in order to use sklearn models is this:

- `X` should be always be an 2D array with shape [n_samples, n_variables]
- `y` should be the target varible.

Comment: hello, quick question: Can I use strings as features with this module? I mean, my actual data set contains features with different data types, like this row: `High,20,Yes,63,Yes` (that's 4 features and the target class). I'm getting *ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'High'* on this line `tree.fit(X, y)`, which is self explanatory but I don't know how to solve it. Or am I just using this module totally wrong and it can only be used for numeric features. thank you

Comment: yes but first you need to use this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: hi, after a day of trying I finally one-hot-encoded the data and fit the tree. all I need now is to show it in graphviz like I was able to do with the examples. happens that after the one-hot-encoding, since I fit the tree with the encoded data, apparently it thinks that there are 16 features (instead of 4 since`High,20,Yes,63` became`[0.,0.,1.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,1.,0.,0.]`) so `export_graphviz(tree,out_file="f.dot",feature_names=list(['F','G','H','I']),class_names=['Yes','No'])`shows *ValueError: Length of feature_names, 4 does not match number of features, 16*. any advice, please?